# How to set semi transparent background color for Android CardView?

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardview

I want to set the backgroundColor of a card view with an argb color. But the result is like this:

[image]

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/infoCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#59448AFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space_16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_8dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:text="This is a sample text"
            android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Define it within `color.xml`

```
<color name="semiTransparentColor">#20ffffff</color>
```

Now set the card view like this way.

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/semiTransparentColor"
```

Here is the code of hexadecimal code of transparency. [link](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4) you can set as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just set this to a card view

```xml
app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

or try with removing the background of your com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: This answer could use an explanation of how setting the elevation relates to setting the background color.